# Pygame not responding when opening the window

Tags: pygame

When I call pygame it doesnt seem to respond and I was wondering if there is a way to fix it

```
def call_Game_Board():#defines a function called call_Game_Board
        print("called the game board")
        AQADO.Game_Board()#returns function AQADO.Game_Board
        pygame.display.update()#Updates the pygame window
```

All help is appriciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are going to have to call ***that*** function to be able to call the other function. So it will be like:

```
#Your code here, including the function you listed#
call_Game_Board()
```

This should solve your problem. I hope this helps you!